# onClick event on React-Router Link tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've made a navbar with some Link tags to route my app and im trying to add a onClick event to them:

```
doSomething() {
    console.log('This link was clicked')
} 

<Link to="/" className="anyclass" onClick={this.doSomething}>Dashboard</Link>
```

But when i click this link the function was no triggered...

There are any way to do this without adding a button, div or span before the Link tag?

Comment: Overriding `onClick` on a `Link` component would defeat the purpose, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to get the event object to add a CSS class when the links is clicked.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to use [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)?

Comment: Is this react router link? And what are you trying to achieve in the function `doSomething`?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) by define your link normally as you should. And when you define `Route` which is responsible for handling path which define on your the defined `Link` you can use render prop instead of using `component` **props**.

your link will be define link this

```
<Link to="/" className="anyclass">Tacos</Link>
```

and the **Route** will be define link this

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" render={() => {
        /* 
        as this is a normal function you can put 
        any code which must be executed before the 
        component which is return by this render prop.
        */

        console.log('This link was clicked');

        // You can render the component which you want to render 
        return <ComponetToRendere />
    }} />
</Router>
```

To learn more about React Router [render prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)